# single letter Top Level Domain TLD in email REGEX

Tags: regex, email, dns, rfc

I have gone through a lot of documents like [RFC 822](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) and [RFC 5322](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) and lot of Regex examples for email field.

All of them allow the single word TLD.For eg

*test@test.c* is valid ,but TLD 'c' ,is it even allowed for TLD's ?

*.com , .in , .uk* etc is OK but I have never seen a single letter TLD , so why is it allowed in all RFC's ?

Comment: This maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411255/is-it-possible-to-have-one-single-character-top-level-domain-name

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075381/what-is-smallest-valid-domain-name/ ; many regex, specially on emails, are completely wrong. Be very careful, and do not reinvent them. You should also remember to separate what exists in the IANA root from what can be done in experiments or private roots...