# Filter out tokens that’s not an email or phone number

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m checking to see if a token is not a phone number or email because it has to be one of those.

I know how to do email:

```
Token NOT LIKE ‘%@%’
```

Not sure how remove phone numbers that have 10 characters length.

All is being coded in Oracle SQL.

I tried:

```
TOKEN NOT LIKE ‘%@%’
AND LENGTH(TOKEN) > 10
```

I got one result back but is this properly check for others that aren’t a phone number token

Comment: In "TOKEN NOT LIKE ‘%@%’ AND LENGTH(TOKEN) > 10" should AND be OR ?

Comment: email address regex would be helpful: https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @JHH See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1509264) for standard compliant regular expressions (and better suggestions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, checks you are performing are rather week. `a@b` contains the `@` sign, but that's not a valid e-mail address. Or, string whose length is lower than 10 characters may be `123AB-$)1` but that's not a valid phone number.

I'm not saying that functions I'm going to post do it 100% right, but should be a lot better than what you're trying to do. Adjust them, if you want.

Phone numbers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
   FUNCTION f_phone (par_telefon IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      /* 21.11.2022 Check whether phone number(s) passed via PAR_TELEFON are
                    valid.
                    
                    Check:
                    - length has to be between 6 (e.g. 654123) and 20 (e.g. +385 91/123-4567) characters
                    - can contain signs: +-/, space, digits
                    
                    Return:
                    - phone number and its errors (if there are any)
                    - NULL if everything is OK
      */
      retval  VARCHAR2 (200);
      l_str   VARCHAR2 (200);     -- list of errors
      l_cnt   NUMBER := 0;        -- number of errors
   BEGIN
      FOR cur_r IN (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (par_telefon,
                                              '[^,]+',
                                              1,
                                              LEVEL) val
                          FROM DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (par_telefon, ',') + 1)
      LOOP
         IF LENGTH (cur_r.val) < 6
         THEN
            l_str := l_str || '; ' || 'too short';
            l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
         ELSIF LENGTH (cur_r.val) > 20
         THEN
            l_str := l_str || '; ' || 'too long';
            l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
         END IF;

         IF TRANSLATE (cur_r.val, '~1234567890-/+ ', '~') IS NOT NULL
         THEN
            l_str := l_str || '; ' || 'allowed: 0-9 +-/';
            l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
         END IF;

         IF l_cnt > 0
         THEN
            retval :=
               retval || '; ' || cur_r.val || ': ' || LTRIM (l_str, '; ');
            l_cnt := 0;
            l_str := NULL;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

      RETURN ltrim(retval, '; ');
   END f_phone;
   /
```

E-mail addresses:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
   FUNCTION f_e_mail (par_e_mail IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      /* 21.11.2022 Check e-mail addresses.
      */
      l_email  VARCHAR2 (200);
      retval   VARCHAR2 (200);
      l_str    VARCHAR2 (200);        -- list of errors
      l_cnt    NUMBER := 0;           -- number of errors
   BEGIN
      l_email := RTRIM (par_e_mail, CHR (13));

      FOR cur_r IN (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (REPLACE (l_email, ' ', ''),
                                                    '[^,]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)) val
                          FROM DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (l_email, ',') + 1)
      LOOP
         IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (
                   cur_r.val,
                   '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$')
         THEN
            l_str := l_str || '; ' || 'invalid e-mail address';
            l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
         END IF;

         IF l_cnt > 0
         THEN
            retval :=
               retval || '; ' || cur_r.val || ': ' || LTRIM (l_str, '; ');
            l_cnt := 0;
            l_str := NULL;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

      RETURN ltrim(retval, '; '); 
   END f_e_mail;
   /
```

---

A test or two:

```
SQL> select f_phone('555 123-456') phone_1,
  2         f_phone('00385-AB-234 234') phone_2,
  3         f_phone('123') phone_3,
  4         f_phone('456ab, +385 81 123-456') phone_4
  5  from dual;

PHONE_1    PHONE_2                                  PHONE_3         PHONE_4
---------- ---------------------------------------- --------------- ----------------------------------------
           00385-AB-234 234: allowed: 0-9 +-/       123: too short  456ab: too short; allowed: 0-9 +-/

SQL>
SQL> select f_e_mail('a@b') mail_1,
  2         f_e_mail('little@stack.com, foot@yahoo') mail_2
  3  from dual;

MAIL_1                                   MAIL_2
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
a@b: invalid e-mail address              foot@yahoo: invalid e-mail address

SQL>
```

Comment: [`a@b` is a valid e-mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423203/1509264). Your regular expression also filters out other valid e-mail addresses such as `example++thisisatest@gmail.com` or `"Abc@def"@example.accountants` or `χρήστης@παράδειγμα.ελ`

Comment: As I said, that's not 100% perfect and anyone - who wants - can improve it. Works OK for **my** needs.

Comment: Oh, yes: @MT0, please, do post your function(s) which perform that check better. I'll gladly copy/paste them into my database and use them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to validate an e-mail address is to send it an e-mail and get the owner to confirm that: it is a valid address; it is the correct address for the owner; and that they wanted to be signed up for your service.

---

Otherwise, if you want to test for a valid e-mail address and you have Java enabled in the database then you can use the JavaMail package.

- Download the JavaMail API and then load the jar into the database with the `loadjava` utility.
- Then compile the class in the database:

  ```
  CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED test_email AS
  import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
  import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;

  public class email {
    public static int validateEmail(String email) {
      try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
        emailAddr.validate();
      } catch (AddressException ex) {
        return 0;
      }
      return 1;
    }
  }
  ```
- Then you can create a PL/SQL wrapper function:

  ```sql
  CREATE FUNCTION validateEmail RETURN NUMBER
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'email.validateEmail(java.lang.String) return int';
  /
  ```

---

If you prefer, instead, you can load and use the Apache Commons Validator package:

- ```
  CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED test_email AS
  import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;

  public class email {
    public static int validateEmail(String email) {
      return EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email) ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }
  ```